# Run Node server as a service

Tags: node.js, web-services, rest

Is a REST service required to be backed by a backend resource?

The use case is this.
I want to run a node server instance that acts as a service to transform a json file into either html, css or js files and return it, and thought about the following endpoints:

- HTML with inline CSS/JS: `/:slug`
- HTML: `/:slug/html`
- CSS: `/:slug/css`
- JS: `/:slug/js`

You see, the endpoints don't actually represent the endpoint of a backend resource. It merely represents a generic endpoint for a client to call if it wants to transform a json file (sent in the request body).

Is this acceptable, or does it go against the REST paradigm?

Comment: How about you do `/convertJSON?id=slug&format=html`, for example... That's only one endpoint... Anyways, to answer your question, no, it's by no means required

Comment: I don't think there is any guide lines or standards for URI end point design. From what I know is that as long as it is not camel case, all lower no funny characters like _ * $, something that can be easily understood by external parties and you should be all good. Please correct me if I am wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a fun idea to build towards a completely RESTful design. My idea would be to treat each as their own endpoint.

```
POST /        everything
POST /css     the css
POST /HTML    the html
POST /JS      the js
```

That way you have more flexibility down the road and can make this functionality visible to other parties in the future, with little hassle in integration!

Hope my input is a little helpful!

Comment: That was also my first idea. I'm a bit in doubt here, given the comment of using query parameters, although I suppose both will work. I also thought about making requests using accept headers.